# How to ignore executable file in devtools::check()

Tags: r, package

Edit: it is actually `devtools::check()` who is causing this warning and not `R CMD check`. I just tried with `R CMD check` and it works with the BinaryFiles!

I feel stupid that I can't figure this out, but I want to add some data to my R-package and I put everything in inst/extdata. Unfortunately on Linux the files are recognized as an executable while they are just a NMR data file (R CMD check uses `file` for this).

The warning I get:

```
checking for executable files ... WARNING
Found the following executable files:
     inst/extdata/Sample123/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample22/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample244/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample281/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample294/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample396/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample40/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample452/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample460/10/fid
     inst/extdata/Sample9999/10/fid
   Source packages should not contain undeclared executable files.
   See section ‘Package structure’ in the ‘Writing R Extensions’ manual.
```

I found in the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-structure) manual that I can silence this warning by adding a file called `BinaryFiles` at the top level of my package. I need to add one line per path, but `devtools::check()` keeps on complaining about these files. My `BinaryFiles` looks like:

```
inst/extdata/Sample123/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample22/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample244/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample281/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample294/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample396/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample40/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample452/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample460/10/fid
inst/extdata/Sample9999/10/fid
```

The file ends with an empty line. I also tried adding `./` in front of the path, but still it doesn't work. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

I created a dummy package. You can find it [here](https://github.com/ricoderks/SomePackage).

Cheers, Rico

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get from R CMD check? Is this package in a repo somewhere that we can inspect and recreate the problem ourselves? It's much easier to help with you provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MrFlick at the moment the repository is private, because it belongs to a publication we are working on. I know this makes it more difficult for me to get help. I'll try to make a dummy package which I can share.

Comment: Just a guess but could it be that those files inadvertently were marked as executable?  If you are on Linux use `chmod -x filename` to turn that off.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, I tried this, but I doesn't matter. I think `R CMD check` doesn't look at this, but only at the result of the `file` command in Linux.